# Want to update column Values for each occurrence of column AppName where at least one of the values in column Values is "Yes" s.t all values are 'Yes'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table

| AppName | Values |
| --- | --- |
| JBX | Yes |
| JBX | No |
| JBX | Yes |
| ABD | No |
| ABD | No |
| CBR | Yes |
| LBA | No |
| LBA | Yes |

And I want to update this table so that for each occurrence of AppName where at least one of the values in the "Values" column is 'Yes' then we update all of the values for that specific AppName to "Yes".

Updated Table:

| AppName | Values |
| --- | --- |
| JBX | Yes |
| JBX | Yes |
| JBX | Yes |
| ABD | No |
| ABD | No |
| CBR | Yes |
| LBA | Yes |
| LBA | Yes |

I tried

````
        if df2['Values'] == 'Yes':
           df2['Values'] == 'Yes'  ```
But this throws a ```ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().``` for ```if df2['Values'] == 'Yes':```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach using [groupby.transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html), placing results into a new column for easy comparison with original `Values` column:

```
df['app_has_any_yes'] = (df.groupby('AppName')['Values']
                           .transform(lambda x: (x == 'Yes').any())
                           .replace({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})
```

Result:

| AppName | Values | app_has_any_yes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JBX | Yes | Yes |
| JBX | No | Yes |
| JBX | Yes | Yes |
| ABD | No | No |
| ABD | No | No |
| CBR | Yes | Yes |
| LBA | No | Yes |
| LBA | Yes | Yes |

Answer (score 1):

Conveniently, "Yes" is lexicographically sorted after "No", so Yes>No and you can do:

```
df['Values'] = df.groupby('AppName')['Values'].transform('max')
```

*NB. this is working for this particular example, but you can use the same logic with other words, for example in German "Ja" (Yes) is before "Nein" (No), so you would use `transform('min')` in this case*

output:

```
  AppName Values
0     JBX    Yes
1     JBX    Yes
2     JBX    Yes
3     ABD     No
4     ABD     No
5     CBR    Yes
6     LBA    Yes
7     LBA    Yes
```

Comment: Exploiting the sort order of the values is a really clever approach!

Comment: Thanks @Peter, yes I think knowing the data is sometimes important to avoid extra computations/steps ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `groupby` then `apply`

```py
out = df.groupby('AppName').apply(lambda g: g.assign(Values=['Yes']*len(g) if g['Values'].eq('Yes').any() else ['No']*len(g)))
```

```
print(out)

  AppName Values
0     JBX    Yes
1     JBX    Yes
2     JBX    Yes
3     ABD     No
4     ABD     No
5     CBR    Yes
6     LBA    Yes
7     LBA    Yes
```